# Loop to display portion of webpage for different cookie value

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

My webpage has a cookie called "cookie_test" and what URL the webpage goes to and what value my webpage shows depends on the value of cookie_test. I am trying to create a greasemonkey script that will iterate through the different values of cookie_test and display a portion of the webpage.

The following is the code I currently have:

```
//Create Cookie Function
function create_cookie(name, value, days2expire, path) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days2expire * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = name + '=' + value + ';' +
                   'expires=' + expires + ';' +
                   'path=' + path + ';';
}

var cookie_name = 'cookie_test';
for(var cookie_value = 1; cookie_value <= 100; cookie_value++) {
    create_cookie(cookie_name, cookie_value, 30, "/"); // Create the cookie
    var url = "http://example.com/?cookie=" + cookie_value; //Will redirect to this URL
    if(document.URL != url) {
        open(url, '_blank'); //If not on this URL, go to this URL
    }
    if(document.getElementsByTagName('strong')) console.log(document.URL + ", " + document.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].innerHTML); //Retrieve content from webpage
}
```

This code is able to work only on the last cookie (when cookie_value = 100) because when I redirect to a new page only the last cookie is set.

How can I have the console display the value my page shows for the different values for `cookie_test`?

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you trying to create a 100 different cookies?  What is the expected output **exactly**?  Is the `open(url` on the same domain? ... Also there is an error with the `if(document.getElementsByTagName('strong'))` test.  You need to use `.length` there.

Comment: One cookie value is changing (from 1 to 100) but i want to retrieve some HTML from the page of example.com/?cookie=[cookie_value]
Yes, it is all on one domain

Comment: Essentially for everyloop I want to change the value of a cookie to be a # between 1 and 100. Once the cookie changes i want to go to url.com/?cookie=# and pull some data from the site.

Comment: Are you able to assist @BrockAdams